# SMTP configuration | Ionos not receiving email

Tags: symfony, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm experiencing some issues with Ionos smtp configuration. 
I use Swiftmailer with Symfony 4. 
On local i receive my email using mailtrap or gmail, but on ionos's server it doesn't work with gmail or the SMTP configuration. 
Here is my .env with different configs :

```
###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://email@gmail.com:PSW@localhost" <-- Work in local but not on Ionos
# MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=LOGINMAILTRAP&password=PASSWORDMAILTRAP <-- Work in local and Ionos
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.ionos.fr:587?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=contact@mydomain.com&password=PWD <-- Doesn't work using Ionos SMTP config
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
```

Here is my swiftmailer.yaml :

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#configuration

> If the username, password or host contain any character considered special in a URI (such as +, @,  $, #, /, :, *, !), you must encode them. See RFC 3986 for the full list of reserved characters or use the urlencode function to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the encryption, from `ssl` to  `tls`.

Here is an example:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.ionos.fr:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=contact@mydomain.com&password=PWD
```

And make sure to urlencode the password if it contains any special charater, as mentioned by @Fisher